# Angluar app on google cloud storage dosn't work

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

I followed this guide to host my angular app on google cloud storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#command-line_2

I have not bought an own domain so I've tried to test with the gcs domain: https://storage.googleapis.com/my-storage/. Entering this domain returns an xml document (list of files in folder).

```
<ListBucketResult>
  <Name>my-storage</Name>
  <Prefix/>
  <Marker/>
  ...
```

If I add index.html `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-storage/index.html` the angular app is loaded and the sub path replaced: [https://storage.googleapis.com/my-storage/auth/login`](https://storage.googleapis.com/my-storage/auth/login%60). If I do a refresh now I will get an error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
```

I set the main and error page to index.html:
`gcloud storage buckets update gs://my-storage --web-main-page-suffix=index.html --web-error-page=index.html`

I also build my angular app with `--base-href='/my-storage/'`.